# rails No route matches [DELETE], but I can see it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I seem to run into these sorts of 'routing' issues somewhat regularly, and they then disappear without my knowing what I've done to improve the situation.

Currently, I have a backbone model which I am deleting

```
    delete_class: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
    }
```

This sends a delete request to the server. In the console I get `DELETE http://192.168.7.25:3000/user_classes 404 (Not Found)`

in my controller, I have

```
  def destroy
    user_class = UserClass.find(params[:id])
    user_class.destroy
   render :text => 'deleted'
  end
```

So clearly it is there. I can make a request to `http://192.168.7.25:3000/user_classes`, and the route is found, so the problem only seems to be when trying to DELETE. I haven't tried update, but index and show both return no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails does also respond with a `404 Not Found` error when an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception occurs. Are your sure your `params` hash contains a correct id and are your sure your backbone send this ID corrently to the server?

Comment: it's this sort of deep knowledge that I'm missing. I did notice that the there weren't any params being sent, but thought I'd deal with one thing at a time.